# encrypting video essence using ffmpeg files

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to create a encrypted mxf file using ffmpeg.
can any one tell me how to encrypt an avi/mpeg file using ffmpeg and save it to mxf format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your use case?

I don't know if ffmpeg can do what you need but there are some MXF tools that can help, here are some links that might help you:

- Have a look at mxfcrypt from mxflib project at http://sourceforge.net/projects/mxflib/
- Or if your use case is DCP related http://www.cinecert.com/asdcplib/

Regards,
Matt